# fadeout and removechild on load

Tags: javascript, animation, onload

I am quite new to scripting, and I am attempting to implement a fading loadscreen on a new site.

When I target the parent div of the load screen (load_screen) and add fadeout and removeChild, the fadeout looks as I'd like it to, but then reappears instead of being removed. How can I change this code?

```
 <script>
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
      var load_screen = document.getElementById("load_screen");
      document.body.fadeOut(load_screen);
      document.body.removeChild(load_screen);
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think this is because you need to let the animation happen first before removing the element. I use jQuery for this because it's a lot easier, but I guess you'd have to use an event handler to catch the animation end, then remove the element.

Comment: So, how would you recommend doing this with jQuery? I haven't really learned jQuery at all other than copy and pasting and manipulating till it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#load_screen').fadeOut(7000);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#load_screen').addClass('hide'); 
    }, 7000);
});
```

CSS

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d2mxx52y/10/

Comment: Actually you don't need the setTimeout here, you can do $('#load_screen').fadeOut(7000, function() { $('#load_screen').addClass('hide'); } ); and let jQuery deal with the event handling. This applies to many jQuery commands that have some sort of duration.